# Selecting from a Select statement: Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to retrieve the last 3 rows but in an ASC order, so here's the final query:

```
SELECT c.comment_id,c.comment_message,c.comment_date,u.user_id,u.first_name,u.last_name,p.profile_picture_path 
FROM 
     (SELECT c.comment_id,c.comment_message,c.comment_date,u.user_id,u.first_name,u.last_name,p.profile_picture_path 
      FROM posts_comments c,users u,users_profile_pictures p 
      WHERE c.user_id = u.user_id AND u.user_id = p.user_id AND c.post_id = '82' 
      ORDER BY c.comment_date DESC 
      LIMIT 3) 
ORDER BY c.comment_date ASC
```

I know there's something wrong here, I'm receiving this error: `Every derived table must have its own alias`. How do I select columns from a Select statement when they are pointed out by their appropriate tables? Means, how do I select `c.comment_id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  comment_id,
        comment_message,
        comment_date,
        user_id,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        profile_picture_path
FROM (
        SELECT  c.comment_id,
                c.comment_message,
                c.comment_date,
                u.user_id,
                u.first_name,
                u.last_name,
                p.profile_picture_path
        FROM    posts_comments c,
                users u,
                users_profile_pictures p
        WHERE   c.user_id = u.user_id
                AND u.user_id = p.user_id
                AND c.post_id = '82'
        ORDER BY c.comment_date DESC 
        LIMIT 3
    ) subA -- <<==  put alias here
           -- the purpose of the alias is to supply an identification 
           -- for the subquery
ORDER BY comment_date ASC
```

Comment: Now I got this: `Unknown column 'c.comment_id' in 'field list'`  `:(`

Comment: sorry for the typo, try the updated query again. `c` is not valid anymore because it is contained in a subquery.

Comment: It Worked `:D` but why does it need an Alias?

Comment: it will give name to identify the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT x.comment_id
      , x.comment_message
      , x.comment_date
      , x.user_id
      , x.first_name
      , x.last_name
      , x.profile_picture_path 
   FROM 
      ( SELECT c.comment_id
             , c.comment_message
             , c.comment_date
             , u.user_id
             , u.first_name
             , u.last_name
             , p.profile_picture_path 
          FROM posts_comments c
          JOIN users u
            ON u.user_id = c.user_id 
          JOIN users_profile_pictures p 
            ON p.user_id = u.user_id 
         WHERE c.post_id = 82 
         ORDER 
            BY c.comment_date DESC 
         LIMIT 3
      ) x 
  ORDER 
     BY x.comment_date ASC;
```